# Weird Apache Error With PHP

Tags: php, apache, session

I am getting the following error in apache:

> [notice] child pid 13190 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

and it only seems to be happening when I try to echo, var_dump, etc... the $data variable in my session write function.  Anything thing that is strange is that if I don't try to var_dump $data with this code:

```
if($this->read($id) == '')
{
    $this->sessionCollection->insert($data, array('safe' => true));
}
else
{
    $this->sessionCollection->update(array('_id' => $data['_id']), $data, array('safe' => true));
}
```

php throws:

> Warning: MongoCollection::insert() expects parameter 1 to be an array
>   or object

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you use exit() in the write method of a session write handler, the segfault is a normal outcome.   I put in the exit because I wanted to see the $data variable because it did not look like the data was saving properly.  Now that I know the $data variable is a strng of a serialized array, it seems to be work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that in line 3 (`...->insert($data ...)`) `$data` is not an array, but a scalar. However, MongoCollection requires an array as [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php)

I would `var_dump($data)` to see what's inside.

Comment: if you read above, I get that apache error when I try to var_dump($data);

Comment: I guess I misunderstood that. This is really strange. You need to verify what's in `$data`. If `var_dump` crashes, something's seriously wrong. Maybe you should look into using a real php debugger, e.g. http://xdebug.org/

Comment: figured out my issue, added the answer.